# SQLCMD passing in double quote to scripting variable

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to pass in double quote to a scripting variable in SQLCMD. Is there a way to do this?

```
sqlcmd -S %serverName% -E -d MSDB -i MyScript.sql -m 1 -v Parameter="\""MyValueInDoubleQuote\"""
```

And my sql script is as follow:

```
--This Parameter variable below is commented out since we will get it from the batch file through sqlcmd
--:SETVAR Parameter "\""MyValueInDoubleQuote\"""


INSERT INTO [MyTable]
           ([AccountTypeID]
           ,[Description])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,$(Parameter))
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your sql script set up in this fashion:

```
DECLARE @myValue VARCHAR(30)
SET @myValue = $(MyParameter)
SELECT @myValue
```

Then you can get a value surrounded by double quotes into @myValue by just enclosing your parameter in single quotes:

```
sqlcmd -S MyDb -i myscript.sql -v MyParameter='"123"'
```

This works because -v is going to replace the `$(MyParameter)` string with the text `'"123"'`. The resulting script will look like this before it is executed:

```
DECLARE @myValue VARCHAR(30)
SET @myValue = '"123"'
SELECT @myValue
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**
This sample is working for me (tested on SQL Server 2008, Windows Server 2K3). It inserts a record into the table variable `@MyTable`, and the value in the `Description` field is enclosed in double quotes:

MyScript.sql (no need for setvar):

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE([AccountTypeID] INT, [Description] VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @MyTable ([AccountTypeID] ,[Description])
VALUES(1, $(Parameter))

SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```

SQLCMD:

```
sqlcmd -S %serverName% -E -d MSDB -i MyScript.sql -m 1 -v Parameter='"MyValue"'
```

If you run that script, you should get the following output, which I think is what you're looking for:

```
(1 rows affected)
AccountTypeID Description
------------- --------------------------------------------------
            1 "MyValue"
```

Comment: I'll try that route however I am using scripting variable. So my variable is as follow:  :SETVAR MyVar "MyValue"

Comment: OK. If my suggestion doesn't work can you post a sample of your SQL script in the question?

Comment: Posted my sql script in the question

Comment: I'd be happy to update my answer, but your update to the question is a little confusing. Are you using SETVAR or not?

Comment: I updated my sql script. The SetVar I am trying to define it from SQLCMD using the -v flag. Hence in the SQL script the SetVar is commented out.

Comment: Please check the update to my answer. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. I am using it against sql server 2005. The sample didn't work for me and for some reason sqlcmd doesn't like the single quote. Error I get is :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near 'MyValue'.

Comment: Weird, that script is working for me on Windows Server 2003 against SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008. I don't think this should matter, but what OS and version of SQLCMD (just run sqlcmd -?) are you using?

Comment: Also, are you sure the INSERT statement in the script looks *exactly* like this: `INSERT INTO @MyTable ([AccountTypeID] ,[Description])
VALUES(1, $(Parameter))`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, you don't need to include the quotes in the variable, as they can be in the sql command, like so:

```
sqlcmd -S %serverName% -E -d MSDB -i MyScript.sql -m 1 -v Parameter="MyValueNoQuotes"
```

and

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
            ([AccountTypeID]
            ,[Description])
      VALUES
            (1
            ,"$(Parameter)")
```

(Though I am more accustomed to use single quotes, as in `,'$(Parameter)'`

Comment: That will script it out as MyValueNoQuotes. I am hoping there is an escape key to put the double quotes in.

Comment: It seems that at sqlcmd level when I pass in as """MyValue""" it will out put as ""MyValue"". While I wanted to get "MyValue" and I am not able to do so.

Comment: I'm missing a point here: why do the double quotes need to be included in the SQLCMD variable? I'm proposing to "move" them into the SQL code, such that they don't need to be part of the variable. In your code you are only using them to delimit the string value being written to the `Description` column.